# How to know the calling Class Name?

Tags: c#

Is there a way know which class has called a function in another class.
Eg:

```
public class A
{
    public static string Aa = "test";
    public void test()
    {
        B.testB();
    }
}

public class B
{
    public static void testB()
    {
        string Bb = A.Aa;

    }
}
```

In the above example, i know the class A function has called the function in class B. But if there are many classes which will call the function in class B and all of those classes will have variable Aa in common, so how can i read its value and assign it to Bb. So in simple

```
string Bb = CalledClassName.Aa;
```

Comment: May I ask why you want to do that?

Comment: Similarly to a button click, you could pass in the sender as an object. You could then get the type by doing sender.GetType();

Comment: @leppie It can be done, but would require generics/reflection and is generally just not a pretty way of doing things

Comment: @JasonLarke: I must be very confused about what is being asked here. Edit: After re-reading, I can confirm that...

Comment: @leppie As am I, I think the OP is missing some fundamental understand of the usage of inheritance/polymorphism. To me the questions sounds as if he would like `B::testB` to return the `Aa` static variable from whichever class is calling the method.

Comment: @Shankar static variables are class members not instance so for all instances of class A there will be only ONE static field Aa. And you can always read it by using it's class name  :    A.Aa

Comment: @poke [Asked a Question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31134254/mytestinitialize-and-mytestcleanup/31135743#31135743) - I have to pass Datatable 'Results' to perform some operations in cleanup. Each codedUI test script i author will have the same variable 'Results' which has to be passed to cleanup function.. so i wanted to know which class is calling to read the 'Results' variable of that class only.

Comment: @ShankarAcharya Why is that `Results` variable static then? You can just make it an instance variable and access that directly.

Answer (score 7):

You could use the [`CallerMemberNameAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute.aspx) that was added with .NET 4.5. This will only get you the member name though:

```
public void SomeMethod ()
{
    OtherMethod();
}

public void OtherMethod ([CallerMemberName] string memberName = null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(memberName);
}
```

The attribute will fill the optional parameter at compile time, so it will actually call `OtherMethod("SomeMethod")`.

---

You *could* also use a combination of accessing the stack trace and using reflection to read the `Aa` property of the type of the calling method. Note that this accesses debugging information, and is very vulnerable to changes in your code. It also has a bad performance, so **you should avoid it**. But just to show you how to use it:

```
public static void testB()
{
    StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();
    Type callingType = stackTrace.GetFrame(1).GetMethod().DeclaringType;
    FieldInfo field = callingType.GetField("Aa", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
    string Bb = (string) field.GetValue(null);

    Console.WriteLine(Bb);
}
```

Comment: That will give the method or property name, not the class name.

Comment: @PatrickHofman If you look at OP’s code, you can see that the assignment is `string Bb = CalledClassName.Aa;` where `Aa` is a constant containing the string `"test"`. So OP is indeed asking for the member name.

Comment: Not sure if I share that opinion. I think OP is calling a property or so.

Comment: Nice implementation using reflection. That would definitely solve the 'static' issue.

Comment: @PatrickHofman But explicit passing of the necessary information, e.g. using an interface like in Amit’s or your answer, would still be the way better solution ;)

Answer (score 5):

Use an interface, pass that in:

```
public interface AaInterface {
   public string GetAa();
}

public class A : AaInterface 
{
    public static string Aa = "test";
    public GetAa() { return Aa; }
    public void test()
    {
        B.testB(this);
    }
}

public class B
{
    public static void testB(AaInterface pAa)
    {
        string Bb = pAa.GetAa();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are looking for something different than you are asking.

You should pass the instance of `A` to your method. All calling methods should pass the instance based on an interface. In that interface you put the properties and methods you want to share. In that way you can call the 'same' method for every passed instance.

```
public interface ISomeInterface
{
    string Aa {get;}
}

public class A : ISomeInterface
{
    public string Aa {get { return "a"; } }
}
```

Then you can pass it to this method:

```
public static void testB(ISomeInterface something)
{
    string Bb = something.Aa;
}
```

**Note that in this case, `Aa` is not allowed to be `static`. You could wrap that static in an instance property though.**

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question correctly then you can pass a reference to a class instance in method as parameter then use 'is' operator to check its type:

```
public class A
{
    public static string Aa = "test";
    public void test(object calledClass)
    {
        if(calledClass is B) Aa = calledClass.Bb;
    }
}
```

When you call this static method from class B just put :

```
A.Test(this)
```

P.S.
This is just an example of logic that you can use to achieve what you want

Answer (score 0):

I geuss you can do something like this:

```
public class A {

    public void test() {
        B.testB(this);
    }
}

public class B {
    public static void testB(object sender) {
        String className = sender.GetType().Name;

    }
}

//To call
A a = new A();
a.test();
```

Comment: This does not compile.

Comment: I changed it a little bit, tested it myself and it works.